# I want to create a DataFrame to check whether random state affects the score

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, regression

I'm trying to create a DataFrame to check whether the different shuffling affects the model r-squared value for Training as well as Testing Dataset.
I tried running for loop to do so but got errors.
I m confused about how to create two columns using pd.DataFrame method where the index is the value of random state for that random state what is the value of r-square for train and test

The code I'm writing:

```
%%time
for i in range(0,100):
    X_train,X_test,y_train,y_test = train_test_split(features,prices,test_size=0.2,random_state=i)
    regr.fit(X_train,y_train)
    
random_try = pd.DataFrame(data=[regr.score(X_train,y_train)],
                          [regr.score(X_test,y_test)],index=[i for i in range(1,100)],columns=['Training score','Testing score'])
```

**Just out of curiosity I want to know.Thank you**

Comment: Please report here the error log

Comment: @Sala  File "<unknown>", line 7
SyntaxError: positional argument follows keyword argument

Comment: Well that's the error.

Comment: train_test_split(features,prices,0.2,0.8,i)

Comment: @Sala what should I write when specifying the data in the DataFrame?

Answer (score 0):

The problem results in the way how you create dataframe:

```py
random_try = pd.DataFrame(data=[regr.score(X_train,y_train)],
                          [regr.score(X_test,y_test)],   <====
                          index=[i for i in range(1,100)],
                          columns=['Training score','Testing score'])
```

By writing `data=`, `index=`, you are passing variables to keyword argument. Look at the line I use `<====` to point out, you pass the parameter directly to function like `function(1)`, the argument where parameter passed to is what we call positional argument.

Python doesn't allow you pass variable to positional argument after keyword argument, that's why you see the error.

Actually, I think you want to use bracket to wrap the line I point out

```py
random_try = pd.DataFrame(data=[[regr.score(X_train,y_train)],
                                [regr.score(X_test,y_test)]],
                          index=[i for i in range(1,100)],
                          columns=['Training score','Testing score'])
```